# What's a good pattern for typehinting with `Literal` and then validating at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Let's say I have a class:

```
from typing import Literal


class Computer:
    def __init__(self, operation: Literal['floor', 'ceil', 'square']):
        if operation not in ('floor', 'ceil', 'square'):
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid operation "{operation}"')
        self._operation = operation

    # ... lots of methods that use `self._operation`, e.g.
    def is_much_larger(self, value: float) -> bool:
        if self._operation == 'square':
            if value > 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

I would like to maintain the list of viable values, i.e. `'floor', 'ceil', 'square'`, in only one place. What's a good recipe for this?

The MyPy [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html) show some ideas with this suggestion of `assert_never` but that's just for MyPy to give an error before runtime, not as a way to maintain a single list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introspect those arguments using the typing module.

```
>>> import typing
>>> Operation = typing.Literal['floor', 'ceil', 'square']
>>> typing.get_args(Operation)
('floor', 'ceil', 'square')
```

You could use a type alias then get the values you want using `typing.get_args`, so something like:

```
import typing

# in Python >= 3.10 , use explicit type alias:
# Operation: typing.TypeAlias = typing.Literal['floor', 'ceil', 'square'
Operation = typing.Literal['floor', 'ceil', 'square']


class Computer:
    def __init__(self, operation: Operation:
        if operation not in typing.get_args(Operation):
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid operation "{operation}"')
        self._operation = operation

    # ... lots of methods that use `self._operation`, e.g.
    def is_much_larger(self, value: float) -> bool:
        if self._operation == 'square':
            if value > 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use an `Enum`.

This encapsulates all the options together and greatly simplifies the type hints. However, it means you have to use this `Enum` whenever you call the function. If you have many functions and many different `Enums`, this gets a bit annoying.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Operation(Enum):
    # All caps by convention
    FLOOR = auto()  
    CEIL = auto()   
    SQUARE = auto()  

class Computer:
    # Type hint is much simpler, especially if there are many options
    def __init__(self, operation: Operation):
        # No need for ValueError check
        self._operation = operation

    def is_much_larger(self, value: float) -> bool:
        # Example usage, always have to compare to Operation.SOMETHING
        if self._operation == Operation.SQUARE:
            return value > 1
        return False
```

Note: `auto()` automatically assigns unique int values to each member (i.e., 1, 2, 3, ...)